# Is it possible to bake to a texture with animatable alpha gradient?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, texture-baking

Starting with a scene like:

[image]

I want to bake to a transparent image like:

[image]

In Gimp a gradient can be added to transparency channel:

[image]

Result should be an animatable alpha-gradient (with high transparency but visible ,then the objects should blend in along x-axis):

[image]

How can this be achieved in Blender?
Ideally all of this:

- initially 20% transparency of objects
- a gradient that allows to make the objects opaque from left to right
- optinally a white border (no transparency at all).

All I get from the attached .blend is something like:

[image]

The transparency is lost after bake.

[image]

Comment: is it enough to  just create the effect with nodes ?

Comment: @Chebhou unfortunately no, I wan't to use it in a game engine (Unity) so that I have only to animate the alpha threshold to blend in the symbols when selected.

Comment: what about image sequence as a texture ?

Comment: I need many of them, still hope that there is an easy solution, the question could probably reduced to 'How to keep transparency when baking more than one (semi)-transparent object to a combined bake type image.

Comment: @Chebhou I updated the question and .blend hopefully it's now more clear what I'm looking for.

Comment: maybe you can create one gradient image ( gray scale ) and  use at as alpha channel for other textures

Comment: @Chebhou Thanks this worked. I did another google search and found this http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?189024-Trying-to-create-transparent-gradient solved it. Would you like to answer the question?

Comment: since I can't give a detailed good solution, i think it's better if you do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no success with baking, but could achieve the desired effect by rendering the image.

- Set the materials alpha channel to initial transparency

[image]

<sup>Materials properties</sup>

- Add a plane with an alpha gradient as texxture behing the scene

  - In Gimp create an image with the required dimensions
  - From the layer context menu select  *Add Layer Mask*
  - [image]
  - Use the Blend Tool to create tha gradient
  - [image]
  - Export to .PNG
- Set camera to orthographic
  [image]
- Render and save the image.